# Cannot change number of audio channels field for mediarecorder

Tags: android, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

For an application, I'm setting up the [`MediaRecorder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder) using the following:

```
mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(AudioSource.MIC);
mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(VideoSource.SURFACE);
CamcorderProfile cpHigh = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
cpHigh.audioChannels = 2; 
mediaRecorder.setProfile(cpHigh);
mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(specifiedWidth, specifiedHeight);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(videoFilename);
try {
  mediaRecorder.prepare();
} catch (Exception e) {
  ...
}
```

Despite setting `cpHigh.audioChannels = 2;` the saved files have mono audio. If I change the code to have `mediaRecorder.setAudioChannels(2);` instead, it still doesn't work; I'm still seeing Mono, instead of Stereo. Any idea why?

Comment: Are you sure that whatever device you're using supports recording in stereo?

Comment: @user496854 Does the `CamcorderProfile` consider device's capabilities for setting its parameters?

Comment: I don't know, but you can easily check -- after  you set  `cpHigh.audioChannels = 2`, and before you start recording, just log the current value of `cpHigh.audioChannels`, and see if it's set to 2

Comment: I should say that it will only tell you if you setting 2 channels "stuck". It won't tell you anything if mediaRecorder doesn't check the hardware capabilities

Comment: Ok. Confirmed that the device has Stereo-recording capability. So it must be the way `numChannels` being set. The attribute `cpHigh.audioChannels` cannot be set directly (it's not stuck). I am now wondering if there's another way to record in 2 channels?